# Create a CSV file variable and POST to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv

At the moment we use a form to create a CSV file to download and save locally. Then use a second form to upload the file and POST it to the other page

PHP to create CSV

```
$var1 = $_POST["var1"];
$var1 = $_POST["var2"];

header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tmog.csv"');
echo $var.",".$var2."\n";
```

HTML form to create CSV

```
<form action="./functions/csv.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    <h4 class="text">&nbsp;Create CSV</h4>
    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="var1" placeholder="Var1"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name='var2' class='form-control'>
            <option value='' selected disabled>Select Plan</option>                 
            <option value='Test'>Test</option>
            <option value='Test1'>Test1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" type="submit">Give me CSV</button></div>
</form>
```

Second form to upload csv file and post to other page

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' action='other_page.cgi' target='rumba_output'>
    <label id='file_browse_indicator'>CSV file:</label> 
    <input name='csv_file' type='file' value='' id='file_browse'>   
    <button name='action' value='submit' id='submit_button' onClick='this.form.submit()'>Go!</button>
</form>
```

Anyway what I am attempting to do is skip the:

- Enter values
- Download > Save
- Upload > Submit

Ideally I would like to just:

- Enter values > submit

So far I have tried to write the csv to temp using php ([Like in this article](http://www.metashock.de/2014/02/create-csv-file-in-memory-php/)) and then POST it using cURL but I discovered i don't have access to cURL on our server.

This is the php which i slashed together

```
$var1 = $_POST["var1"];
$var2 = $_POST["var2"];


$fd = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:1048576', 'w');
if($fd === FALSE) {
    die('Failed to open temporary file');
}

$values = array($var1, $var2);

fputcsv($fd, $values);
rewind($fd);
$csv = stream_get_contents($fd);
fclose($fd);


//post to other_page.cgi
$url = 'http://domain.com/other_page.cgi';
$fields = array('csv_file' => $csv);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Obviously I don't have a great understanding of this but any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cURL would be a good solution in your case. It is very strange that cURL is disabled on your server, it is widespread. Try to enable it or install.

However, there are other ways in PHP to POST data (files, as well) except cURL.

1) Read about *stream_context_create* function. Also, maybe this link will be helpful:

http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10372972-RESOLVED-can-I-upload-a-file-using-file_get_contents&s=a1392ce2e27e37513ce9ec62562a3ff0&p=10950863&viewfull=1#post10950863

2) I use HttpRequest in my projects and find it very useful. You can read more in official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php

Comment: Awesome! thanks, I will read up on these. Does the CSV part of the code look like it would work?

Comment: It is not clear for me, why are you writing only one line to your CSV-file. CSV if a format that stores a list of grouped values separated by comma, but in your example I only see two variables at one line. So, what is the reason to use CSV? It's like creating Excel table with two words at one line in it - senseless idea (better to use text file if you only have a few characters, all at one line).

Comment: Well the other_page.cgi only accepts a csv file and I have no control at all over that server. So it sort of forces me to use that format unfortunately